# Scrape url from an image using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape links of images from [this website](https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?page=1)

The image that appears early in the page has its url as

```
<img src="//sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1jvmMXmtYBeNjSspkq6zU8VXa3/Closed-Cell-Expanded-Perlite-Bulk-Expanded-Perlite.jpg_300x300.jpg" alt="Closed Cell Expanded Perlite Bulk Expanded Perlite Price" />
```

The image that appears later has its url as,

```
<img src="//img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1S_7kkY5YBuNjSspoXXbeNFXa-700-700.jpg_350x350.jpg" data-src="//sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1IXB5abwTMeJjSszfq6xbtFXaQ/Expanded-Perlite-for-Agriculture.jpg_300x300.jpg" alt="Expanded Perlite for Agriculture" />
```

The `src` in the second case contains a link to a universal image that appears before the actual image of the page loads and `data_src` is the actual url to be scrapped.

So I tried this code to scrape url using ternary expressions (if else).

### My code

```
import scrapy

class AlibabaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?page=1']

def parse(self, response):
    url = '//img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1S_7kkY5YBuNjSspoXXbeNFXa-700-700.jpg_350x350.jpg'
    for products in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "m-gallery-product-item-wrap")]'):
        img_url_datasrc = products.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img/@data-src').extract_first()
        img_url_src = products.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img/@src').extract_first()
        item = {
        'product_name': products.xpath('.//h2/a/@title').extract_first(),
        'image_url': img_url_datasrc if img_url_src == url else img_url_src, #This is problem
        }
        yield item
```

The result is not of the kind that I want.

### Edit

Result of the query:

```
img_url_datasrc if img_url_src == url else img_url_src
```

[image]

Comment: I am able to get the image url in `scrapy shell` using `response.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img/@src').extract_first()`. Which is `'//sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1jvmMXmtYBeNjSspkq6zU8VXa3/Closed-Cell-Expanded-Perlite-Bulk-Expanded-Perlite.jpg_300x300.jpg'` .

Comment: The code won't be functional in images as we scroll down.  It will give this `//img.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1S_7kkY5YBuNjSspoXXbeNFXa-700-700.jpg_350x350.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
'image_url': img_url_datasrc if img_url_src == url else img_url_datasrc, #This is problem
```

This is indeed the problem, you set the image url to `img_url_datasrc` in both cases.
You probably wanted:

```
'image_url': img_url_datasrc if img_url_src == url else img_url_src,
```

Comment: The problem remains the same. how can we solve it? Please see the edit version of the question. and thanks for showing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one =)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class AlibabaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibaba'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/catalog/agricultural-growing-media_cid144?page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//div[@class="m-gallery-product-item-v2"]')
        img_data_url = ''

        for product in products:
            if product.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img[contains(@src, "tfs")]'):
                img_data_url = product.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img/@data-src').extract_first()
            else:
                img_data_url = product.xpath('.//div[@class="offer-image-box"]/img/@src').extract_first()

            item = {
                'product_name': product.xpath('.//h2/a/@title').extract_first(),
                'image_url': img_data_url,
            }
            yield item
```

> result.json

[image: result.json]